# Implement Master detail in ag-grid without an enterpirise license

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Is there any way I can implement a master-detail feature in ag-grid for angular,without having the enterprise edition?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose yea, possible, [check here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/). 
But it wouldn't be exactly as Master\Detail, cuz inbuilt feature provides more than just displaying data, it's handled as an isolated grid with own functionality. Might be there is a possibility to put ag-grid inside to full-with renderer, but I guess it will bring more complexity and hard-maintainable code.